# How to move a row to the last Row of a Named Range (onEdit)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like this script to move `row` to the bottom of a named range ("APPROVED")

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

   if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "APPROVED") {

      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var namedRange = ss.getRangeByName('APPROVED');
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange);
      s.deleteRow(row)
   } 
}
```

The script currently overwrites the first row in the named range. I've tried the following

```
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var namedRange = ss.getRangeByName('APPROVED');
var target = (namedRange.getLastRow() +1, 1));
s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row)
```

I'm certainly a novice with GAS so any elaborations on fixes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to move a row to the last row of `namedRange`.

If my understanding is correct, as another solution, how about this modification? I think that the approach of your 2nd script is close to the goal. So in this answer, I used `moveTo()`. Because I thought that this approach might be also useful for other users, I posted this. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### From:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange);
```

#### To:

```
 s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange.offset(namedRange.getLastRow() - namedRange.getRow(), 0));
```

- In this modification, put a row to the last row of `namedRange` using `offset()`.
- If you want to put the row to the next row of the last row of `namedRange`, please modify as follows.

  - `s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange.offset(namedRange.getLastRow() - namedRange.getRow() + 1, 0))`

#### Note:

- In your script, `moveTo()` is used. So this line of `s.deleteRow(row)` might be able to be deleted. About this, please do this for your situation.

#### References:

- [offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset)
- [moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to put a row to the last row in the named range.
- In this case, the last row is the last row in the named range.

  - For example, the named range has 40 rows and some values are put in the first 5 rows, you want to put the row from 6 row.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange);
```

#### To:

```
var values = namedRange.getValues();
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var r = values[i].some(function(e) {return e});
  if (r) {
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1,numColumns).moveTo(namedRange.offset(i + 1, 0));
    break;
  }
}
```

- `namedRange.getLastRow()` retrieves the maximum row number of the named range. So I prepared the script for retrieving the last row in the named range.

Comment: This is nearly perfect! The goal I have is to move the adjusted row to the row following the last row of _content_ within the named Range. If the named range includes 40 rows but only has 5 rows of content, this row would move to the 6th row within the named range. I hope that makes sense! Thanks again for answering one of my many apps script questions.

Comment: @Softserve Thank you for replying. I could understand that I misunderstood your question. I apologize. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Softserve Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi, yes this solution worked as intended! Thank you. Unfortunately I decided that using a named range would ultimately not work for my intended goal. My goal here is to have multiple sections within one Sheet as stated above. The workaround I'm using is to apply a value to each "Status" in a separate hidden column. This allows me to sort by these values using an onEdit script I created. I would prefer to be able to give this array of statuses  values in the script editor but I am not sure how to accomplish that. Sorry if that is horribly confusing!

Comment: Example of what I'm currently doing is ["Yes" header = 0, "Yes" = 1, "No" header= 2, "No" = 3]. This ensures that the "Yes" rows always shift under the Yes header. I'm aware this solution only works with values 1-9 given how sort() operates. The issue with this solution is that it doesn't handle blanks well and the aforementioned sort problem. Here's the new solution I'm using if you care to chime in, no worries if not :)

Comment: @Softserve Thank you for replying. I'm glad your initial issue was resolved. About your new issue, I cannot understand yet. I apologize for this. So can you post it as new question? At that time, please include the detail information. And also please close this question, because your initial issue was resolved. By this, other users can see your question was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setLastRowOfANamedRange(row,s,nr) {
  var nr=nr || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('APPROVED');//debug
  var s=s || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();//debug
  var row=row || 5;//debug
  var vA=nr.getValues();
  vA[vA.length-1]=s.getRange(row,1,1,vA[0].length).getValues();
  nr.setValues(vA);
}
```